# How to use Playwright package in Express.js with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I use Express.js with Node.js and I want to parse information when I access to specific route like `/search`.

So I create `/search` route with GET method and when I access to /search route.

So my `search.js` file is like this.

```
const firefox = require('playwright');
/**
 * GET /
 * Result page.
 */
exports.index = async (req, res) => {
  // let searchKeyword = req.body.search;
  (async () => {
    const browser = await firefox.launch({ headless: true });
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'sample.png' });
    await browser.close();
  })();
}
```

But when I load this file with `node app.js` It shows me an error.

```
(node:21100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: firefox.launch is not a function
    at C:\Users\person\Documents\GitHub\PandoraCube\controllers\search.js:24:35
    at exports.index (C:\Users\person\Documents\GitHub\PandoraCube\controllers\search.js:65:5)
```

When I try to use Playwright seperately it works fine, but when I put code into Express code. it doesn't works. How can I fix this problem?

I already search error message in Google but it seems that there are no similar case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the import:

```
const {firefox} = require('playwright');
```